# Parsing a string with sed

Tags: sed, csh

I have a string like `prefix-2020.80-suffix-1`
Here are all of possible combinations of input string

```
"2020.80-suffix-1"
"2020.80-suffix"
"prefix-2020.80"
"prefix-2020.80-1"
```

I need to cut out and **assign** `2020` to a variable but cannot get my desired output

Here what i got so far...

```
set var=`echo "prefix-2020.80-suffix-1" | sed "s/[[:alnum:]]*-*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/"`
```

My regexp does not work for other cases and i cannot figure out why! its more complicated that python's regexp syntax

Comment: What sed are you using ?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do `s/2020//`?

Comment: @TomFenech I need to assign that number to a variable that why im trying to parse and get it into a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for all you inputs

```
sed 's/.*\(^\|-\)\([0-9]*\)\..*/\2/' test
```

Matches the start of the line or everything up to `-[number].` and captures the number.

The problem with the original you were using was you didn't take into account when there wasn't a prefix.

Comment: @PYPL No problem, easy mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `grep -oP`:

```
echo "prefix-2020.80-suffix-1" | grep -oP '^([[:alnum:]]+-)?\K[0-9]+'
2020
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE3aX3/2)

Comment: Sorry i did not clearly said what do i want, i need to get 2020 instead of getting rid of it

Comment: Think they only want the 2020 to be printed.

Comment: @PYPL: It was based on earlier question. It is edited now. You will get `2020` for all the cases now using updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed (with extended regex):

```
echo "prefix-2020.80-suffix-1" |sed -r 's/^([^-]*-|)([0-9]+).*/\2/'
```

Using `grep`:

```
echo "prefix-2020.80-suffix-1" |grep -oP "^([^-]*-|)\K\d+"
2020
```

`-P` is for Perl regex.